# cURL error 3 on Symfony on symfony API testing with Phpunit

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, symfony6

I'm making a test for an API enpoint but I'm geting an error

```
public function testRequest(): void
    {
           
        $client = new Client([
            'base_url' => 'http://localhost:8000',
            'defaults' => [
                'exceptions' => false
            ]
        ]);
       
        $response = $client->get('/api/products');
        $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
    }
```

I get this error

```
1) App\Tests\Controller\ApiControllerTest::testRequest        
GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 3:  (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for /api/products
```

The tested endpoint url is `http://localhost:8000/api/products` I think the on the  test y correct

Comment: try using `base_uri` instead of `base_url`. That might be what's causing this. (Or there might be some other problem in addition to that.)

Comment: Today i got the same. already solved it?
Think has something todo with doctrine setup / truncat fixtures